# How to use exit status inside timeout bash -c command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running a small script to essentially poll a newly created AWS instances for SSH access. I want it to poll up to 60 seconds, which is why I am using the linux `timeout` command.

I've got a small script that runs a while loop within a timeout command.

"Full" script for reference. You can assume the IP address is correct

```sh
  # poll for SSH access
  timeout_threshold=60
  INSTANCE_IP=199.199.199.199
  timeout $timeout_threshold bash -c "while true; do
    ssh -oConnectTimeout=2 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ${INSTANCE_IP} exit
    response_code=$?
    if (( response_code == 0 )); then
      echo \"Successfully connected to instance via SSH.\"
      exit
    else
      echo \"Failed to connect by ssh. Trying again in 5 seconds...\"
      sleep 5
    fi
  done"
```

The key part of the polling is

```sh
    ssh -oConnectTimeout=2 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ${INSTANCE_IP} exit
    response_code=$?
```

The problem is that the exit status (i.e. $?) is always empty, resulting in this output:

```sh
line 4: ((: == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 0 ")
Failed to connect by ssh. Trying again in 5 seconds...
```

How can I use the exit status when the commands are executed with  a `bash -c` command?

Comment: You use `"` . All the `$var` variables are expanded before `bash` is even run. It would be way cleaner to just use a function. You can, you need to export it and call bash with it. Like ex. `export -f function; timeout "$timeout_threashold" bash -c 'function "$@"' -- "$INSTANCE_IP"`

Comment: Afaik you can't use the timeout command with a function? When I tried, it did throw some errors for me, but if you say it should work, I'll give it another go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in your script, is that `$?` is expanded *before* bash is even run. It's always going to be zero or empty.

You could do change the quotes, from `"` to `'`. Remember to expand variables that you want to expand properly. Alternatively, you could just change escape `$?` into `\$?`.

```
timeout "$timeout_threshold" bash -c 'while true; do
    ssh -oConnectTimeout=2 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q '"${INSTANCE_IP}"' exit
    response_code=$?
    if (( response_code == 0 )); then
      echo "Successfully connected to instance via SSH."
      exit
    else
      echo "Failed to connect by ssh. Trying again in 5 seconds..."
      sleep 5
    fi
  done'
```

Or use a function:

```
connect() {
    # I pass the instance as the first argument
    # alternatively you could export INSTANCE_IP from parent shell
    INSTANCE_IP="$1"
    while true; do
       ssh -oConnectTimeout=2 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q "$INSTANCE_IP" exit
       response_code=$?
       if (( response_code == 0 )); then
          echo "Successfully connected to instance via SSH."
          exit
       else
          echo "Failed to connect by ssh. Trying again in 5 seconds..."
          sleep 5
       fi
    done
}

timeout_threshold=60
INSTANCE_IP=199.199.199.199

# function needs to be exprted to be used inside child bashs
export -f connect

timeout "$timeout_threshold" bash -c 'connect "$@"' -- "$INSTANCE_IP"
```